# Count different arrangments

Tags: algorithm

Few friends are going to a party. Each person has his own collection of T-Shirts. There are 100 different kind of T-Shirts. Each T-Shirt has a unique id between 1 and 100. No person has two T-Shirts of the same ID.

They want to know **how many arrangements are there in which no two persons wear same T-Shirt.** One arrangement is considered different from another arrangement if there is at least one person wearing a different kind of T-Shirt in another arrangement.

**Example 1 :** If Their are 2(=N) friends and Each of the next N lines (in this case 2 lines) contains at least 1 and at most 100 space separated distinct integers, denoting the ID's of the T-Shirts ith person has.

```
3 5
8 100
```

Answer for this case is 4

Explanation : 4 possible ways are (3,8), (3,100), (5,8) and (5,100).

**Example 2** : If N=3 and collection with each of 3 friends is as follow :

```
5 100 1
2
5 100
```

Then here also answer will be 4 as 4 possible ways are (5,2,100), (100,2,5), (1,2,100), and (1,2,5).

I want an efficient algorithm to count these arrangmnet as brute force will be pretty slow for this problem.

Comment: I was trying to built a brute force solution for this problme.But as their can be 100 Tshirts and N can be atmost 10 then we got 10! * 100 as complexity But i need to optimise it

Comment: I believe there is a dynamic programming recurrence with cost about 100*2^10 for 10 people and 100 t-shirts, which I could explain further if the question was opened - derive the answer for 100 t-shirts from the answer for 99 t-shirts.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - that's the thing: people rush to downvote newcomer's questions without trying to understand them. I think "young and talented" should be more welcomed on the site - it's a moderator job as well

Comment: Understood, @HEKTO, and I agree with the principle wholeheartedly. We'd (obviously) disagree on some specifics. I do applaud and appreciate your helpfulness here, I want to reinforce. Just one tiny thing; try to be a tiny bit more careful how you word some things. Someone actually saw the comment I said was 'insulting' as 'offensive'. I didn't agree (to deleting it), but people can sometimes be very sensitive. You and I clearly have thicker skins! Also; I'm going to be wiping most of our comment 'thread' here just to clean up, in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are talking about belongs to [Graph Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). You want an algorithm to count maximal [Matchings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in a [Bipartite Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). The counting itself belongs to the area of [Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

So, I think it's enough keywords for you here to start searching. There is a number of research papers about this subject, for example [this one](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.8179&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

**UPDATE:**

It looks like you silently assume, that *all* friends will have t-shirts (which might be wrong in general case). So, you want to count *semi-perfect* matchings (a [Perfect Matching](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html) is a matching, which covers all vertices). It makes sense to look for algorithms which can count this kind of matchings.

Comment: How Bipartite matching ?Means what are the two sets you are dividing it into ?

Comment: Also please explain the approach you are thinking about?How are you reducing it to Bipartite graph is one of the important question

Comment: Friends - one set, shirts - another set. "A friend owns a shirt" means you have an edge connecting a vertex from one set to a vertex from another set. "A friend wears a shirt" is a matching, because he/she can't wear more than one shirt, the same for shirts. Maximal matching - all friends wear some shirts.

Comment: Then?Are you sure you get the question properly ?

Comment: Please quote an example to explain your approach

Comment: Your first example: friends - `(A, B)`, shirts - `(3, 5, 8, 100)`. The relationship "owns" is: `(A, 3), (A, 5), (B, 8), (B, 100)`

Comment: How maximal matching will yield answer 4 for this.It will give 2.Dont you think so?

Comment: Each maximal matching is a subset of a set of edges. All matchings are: `[(A, 3), (B, 8)]`, `[(A, 3), (B, 100)]`, `[(A, 5), (B, 8)]`, `[(A, 5), (B, 100)]`

Comment: You mean to find all maximal matchings ?

Comment: Finding all maximal matchings and counting them are two different problems. Anyway, it's a high-caliber graph theory + combinatorics, so please don't expect that some simple and effective algorithm already exists. At least, I don't know such an algorithm